# How can I copy files from A to B, only including files that exist in B?

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer, robocopy

I'm on Windows 7 Professional, and this is my scenario :

```
Folder "Asd" (C:\)              Folder "Asd" (D:\)
File 1                          File 1 
File 2                          File 3 
File 3                          File 4
File 4
File 5
```

I'd like to select the folder on C:\ (without selecting each single file, of course) and copy it over the same folder on D:. Usually, it will copy all files. But what I'm looking for is to copy only files (from C:) that are contained on folder d:.

So in my case I'd like to replace only File 1, File 3 and File 4. 
File 2 and File 5 must be ignored.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you want to copy, [robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) always has the right switch to do it.
Here you want the [`/XL`](https://superuser.com/questions/314503/what-does-robocopy-mean-by-tweaked-lonely-and-extra) switch to exclude “lonely” files:

```
robocopy C:\ D:\ /S /XL
```

This will work with files or folders.

Answer (score 6):

Try using **`XCOPY`** command:-

## Syntax:

```
xcopy sourceDirectory DestinationDirectory /U /Y

 /U           Copies only files that already exist in destination.
 /Y           Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an
              existing destination file.
```

### Example:

```
xcopy D:\Temp\test\*.* D:\Temp\test11 /U /Y
```

**`*.*`** - indicates all files in this directory

Here it overrides the files in destination folder **"D:\Temp\test11"** folder with the files from source

Answer (score 1):

A simple for-loop combined with a `dir /b` should work. Something like this:

```
FOR /F %X IN ('dir /b D:\Asd') DO copy "C:\Asd\%X" "D:\Asd\%X"
```

If you're using a batch file, replace `%X` with `%%X` (something to do with they way how Windows processes variables, it's different from the command line).

Comment: OH! With GUI is it not possible?

Comment: @Markzz, no I don't think so. Oldskool, shouldn't that be "FOR /F %X IN ('dir /b D:\Asd')..." ?

Comment: @markzzz Ah, didn't realize it had to be a GUI solution. Windows doesn't have that kind of functionality by default, you'd probably have to look for a custom piece of software that does that if command-line is not an option.

Comment: @RJFalconer You are right! Updated the answer, thanks.

Comment: @markzzz I think that the tool [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/index.htm) does have a [directory comparison function](http://www.ghisler.com/screenshots/en/08.html) that you could use for this.

Comment: @Oldskool - I would make a little change: `FOR /F %X IN ('dir /b D:\Asd') DO` **if exist "C:\Asd\%X"** `copy "C:\Asd\%X" "D:\Asd\%X"` to prevent trying to copy files that don't exist on C: but do exist on D:

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Troubleshooting IT Issues blog](http://tshootissues.blogspot.sg/) for solution for Robocopy rooting files like PST

> ```
> net use n: \\server\backup
> echo %computername%
> mkdir n:\%computername%
> SET SourceDir= n:\%computername%
> SET Log="n:\%computername%.log"
> robocopy c:\ %SourceDir% *.doc* *.ppt* *.xls* *.pst* *.pdf /s /LOG:%Log%
> ```
>
> The addition of * on either side of the office documents is to ensure
>   that you copy all versions from Office-2k3 and above.  I have also
>   included the PST files.

Answer (score 0):

To go alongside the `robocopy` and `xcopy` methods, here's the solution with [JP Software's TCC/LE](http://jpsoft.com./tccle_cmd_replacement.html) and [`copy`](http://jpsoft.com./help/copy.htm):

```
copy /c c:\asd\ d:\asd\
```