# How can I copy files from A to C, only including files that exist in B?

Tags: windows, file-transfer, robocopy

in reference to this [How can I copy files from A to B, only including files that exist in B?](https://superuser.com/questions/386460/how-can-i-copy-files-from-a-to-b-only-including-files-that-exist-in-b). How can i copy files from A to **C** only including files that exist in B.

```
Folder "A" (C:\)              Folder "B" (D:\)   Folder "C"(E:\)
File 1                          File 1               
File 2                          File 3 
File 3                          File 4
File 4                          File 6
File 5                          File 7
```

Folder C is currently empty. So in my case I'd like to copy only File 1, File 3 and File 4 to Folder C. File 2, File 5, File 6 and File 7 must be ignored.
The answer for the reference question was to use

```
robocopy C:\ D:\ /S /XL
```

but this copies the three files from A to B, i want the three files to be copied to C.

Is what i am asking possible?

Comment: Why you not copy the files in B driectly into C? Is there any specific reason  or requirement to do so?

Comment: i have updated it above but folder B contains extra files that i don't want in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very simple follow this steps:

1. Make 2 new folders D and E.
2. Copy all the files of A into D and B into E.
3. Select all files of D and cut it.
4. Paste these files into E. By doing this the files which are already exist in folder E for that windows ask you what to do for that files. You have to skip the cut operation for that files.
5. The remaining files in folder D are the files that you want to copy in folder C.

Comment: that works but is there any way to do that with command prompt more easily?

Comment: Sorry I know only this way and I do not know if other way exist to do that.