# How do I hide "Extra File" and "100%" lines from robocopy output?

Tags: windows, robocopy

I have a robocopy script to back up our Kiln repositories that runs nightly, which looks something like this:

```
robocopy "$liveRepoLocation" "$cloneRepoLocation" /MIR /MT /W:3 /R:100 /LOG:"$backupLogLocation\BackupKiln.txt" /NFL /NDL /NP
```

In the output, there are a ton of lines that contain "Extra file"s, like this:

```
*EXTRA File              153    E:\Kiln Backup\elasticsearch\data\elasticsearch-kiln\nodes\0\indices\kiln-2\0\index\_yxe.fdt
*EXTRA File               12    E:\Kiln Backup\elasticsearch\data\elasticsearch-kiln\nodes\0\indices\kiln-2\0\index\_yxe.fdx
*EXTRA File              128    E:\Kiln Backup\elasticsearch\data\elasticsearch-kiln\nodes\0\indices\kiln-2\0\index\_yxe.fnm
*EXTRA File              363    E:\Kiln Backup\elasticsearch\data\elasticsearch-kiln\nodes\0\indices\kiln-2\0\index\_yxe.frq
*EXTRA File               13    E:\Kiln Backup\elasticsearch\data\elasticsearch-kiln\nodes\0\indices\kiln-2\0\index\_yxe.nrm
```

Additionally, there are then hundreds of lines at the bottom that contain nothing but "100%"s, like this:

```
100%  
100%  
100%  
100%  
100%  
100%  
100%
```

In addition to making the log files enormous (there are a lot of folders/files in Kiln repos), it makes it annoying to scan through the logs now and then to see if everything was working ok.

1. How do I stop "Extra Files" appearing in the log? (edit: the whole rows, not just the text as /NC will stop)
2. How do I stop these silly "100%" lines appearing in the log?

I've tried every combination of switch I can think of (the current switches are listed above in the command), but neither seem to hide these!

Comment: According to http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html it should be working. Have you tried changing the params order to mirror the documentation?
That would be: /L /NP  /LOG:file /UNILOG:file /LOG+:file /UNILOG+:file /TS /FP /NS /NC /NFL /NDL /TEE /NJH /NJS

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just noticed you are missing a /NC there.

/NC: No Class - don’t log file classes.

Class files are... [What does robocopy mean by tweaked, lonely and extra?](https://superuser.com/questions/314503/what-does-robocopy-mean-by-tweaked-lonely-and-extra)

So I'd try: 
robocopy "$liveRepoLocation" "$cloneRepoLocation" /MIR /MT /W:3 /R:100 /NP /LOG:"$backupLogLocation\BackupKiln.txt" /NC

**Edit 1**

My bad. Didn't see you had already mentioned trying /NC

I've tested here. It seems that the /MIR option ignores the logging options. Also /MT messes it up, adding the 100%.

The only way I got working was

> D:\robocopy>robocopy source destination /MIR /W:3 /R:100 /NS /NC /NFL /NDL /NP /LOG:log.txt".

*It actually works with /MIR. But you have to specify /NFL ***and*** /NDL.* Don't know if that's acceptable for you.

If you try /MT, it will still show the silly 100%

**Edit 2**

I know the question was about Robocopy but I think you should give RichCopy a try 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx

Here's the command line:

> richcopy "D:\robocopy\source"  "D:\robocopy\destination" /P /QO /QP "D:\robocopy\report.log" /UE /US /UD /UPC /UFC /USC /UPR /UET

It starts RichCopy's GUI and closes when done.

And here's the log

> 28/11/2012 11:35:19,0,Copy start,
>
> 28/11/2012 11:35:20,0,Source path : D:\robocopy\source,
>
> 28/11/2012 11:35:20,0,Destination path : d:\robocopy\destination,
>
> 28/11/2012 11:35:20,0,Source file count : 12 files,
>
> 28/11/2012 11:35:20,0,Copied file count : 13 files,
>
> 28/11/2012 11:35:20,0,Purged file count : 1,224 files,
>
> 28/11/2012 11:35:20,0,Elapsed time : 00:00:01,
>
> 28/11/2012 11:35:20,0,Average performance : 1,641,528 bytes / sec,
>
> 28/11/2012 11:35:20,0,Average performance : 13 files / sec,
>
> 28/11/2012 11:35:20,0,Copy complete,D:\robocopy\source

Comment: /NC just removes the "Extra File" column, so the text isn't shown. The rest of the line is still included. I don't want the line at all; I just want the summary :(

Comment: My bad. Didn't see you had already mentioned that. 
I've tested here. It seems that the /MIR option ignores the logging options. Also /MT messes it up. The only way I got working was "
D:\robocopy>robocopy source destination /MIR /W:3 /R:100 /NS /NC /NFL /NDL /NP /LOG:log.txt". If you try /MT, it will still show the silly 100%.

Comment: The 100%'s are the worst part (far more of them than extra files); didn't realised it was MT doing this, so might remove that if it's not giving a huge benefit!

Comment: Marking this as correct as it's a solution to the 100%'s, and I don't think there's a solution to the "Extra file" logging with /MIR :(

Comment: I just edited my original answer. Just posting a new comment so you won't miss it.

Comment: Thanks for the info; it's not important enough for me to change (everything works, it's just a little convenience), but handy to know for future :-)

Comment: @LuizAngelo: I assume you didn't want to repeat /NFL twice, so I corrected the typo. If the edit was incorrect, you can revert it.

Comment: The 100% were acknowledged as a bug in robocopy when the /mt switch is used. Might have been fixed in later versions of robocopy? Certainly present in the Windows Server 2012 variant

Answer (score 11):

The `/XX` option excludes the extra files from being listed. Perversely, this option is listed in `File Selection` options, not `Logging`. It is the opposite of the `/X` logging option, I guess.

Comment: I believe /XX prevents you from selecting the extra files, and /X is just for logging, but allows you display EVEN MORE extra files !  The /XX did the trick for me.

Comment: -1, because /XX leaves the extra file on the destination, instead of deleting it, as expected of the mirroring process.

Comment: As above - /XX negates the /MIR switch in that it leaves extra files in the destination and therefore isn't a mirror anymore

Answer (score 4):

I think this may work:

```
robocopy sourceDir targetDir *.* /njh /njs /ndl /np | find /v "*EXTRA File"
```

So just pipe the output to "find" with the /V for excluding lines which contain the specified text "*Extra File".

Comment: How to exclude the % progress (0 to 100% counter) from the log only (but still visible on the console)?

Comment: +1 This is a brilliant answer!

Comment: While this does work, it also slows down the whole operation (since piping is very slow in batch in general). Just something to keep in mind if you care about performance.

Answer (score 0):

how about using the switches

```
 /MIR /MT /W:3 /R:100 /NFL /NDL /NP 2>&1 | findstr /v /L /C:" * EXTRA " | findstr /v /L /C:"100%%" > "log file name with or without path"
```

so you have

```
robocopy "$liveRepoLocation" "$cloneRepoLocation" /MIR /MT /W:3 /R:100 /NFL /NDL /NP 2>&1 | findstr /v /L /C:" * EXTRA " | findstr /v /L /C:"100%%" > "$backupLogLocation\BackupKiln.txt"
```

- the double %% is required to have a % in the search string
- the ***2>&1*** redirects the stderr stream to stdout because some messages are written to stderr and we want to capture those lines like the /LOG switch does.
- the 2 findstr commands with the /v switch finds all lines that do not contain the search string
- the ***> "log filename"*** redirects the final output to your log file.  If you would normally use ***/LOG:+*** then use ***>> "log filename"*** instead

Notes: if you are using this in a powershell script, like you seem to be, you need to use findstr instead of find like you can in a .bat or .cmd file.  Note the /L and /C: are not supported by find but for the find command they are not required.