# How to Robocopy only modified files and exclude new files

Tags: robocopy

How can I Robocopy only modified files and exclude newly created files in source folder. I'm using windows 7

Answer (score 1):

```
/XL :: eXclude Lonely files and directories
```

Courtesy of `robocopy /?`

See also [What does Robocopy mean by tweaked, lonely, and extra?](https://superuser.com/questions/314503/what-does-robocopy-mean-by-tweaked-lonely-and-extra) post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try  switches like :
/maxlad   and   /minlad
check this link, I think it can helps

[Robocopy command to copy updated files and long path names](https://superuser.com/questions/1519537/robocopy-command-to-copy-updated-files-and-long-path-names/1522132#1522132)

Answer (score -1):

Robocopy just copy files that have changed (in size or modified date, by default). If a file has not changed, Robocopy by default skips it, and copies nothing for the file. But if the two server have the different file systems, files are still re-copied, even though nothing has changed. You can use /fft switch, which makes the modify time comparison more tolerant (2 seconds granularity). There is a similar thread, please go through it to help troubleshoot this issue:Robocopy - want it to only copy new and updated files...http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3123bc0c-ee2e-4692-b346-769803651520/robocopy-want-it-to-only-copy-new-and-updated-files?forum=ITCG
Regards,

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question which was how to copy modifed files but **NOT** new files.