# Robocopy: how to copy all files in folder newer than a specific date (including older files)

Tags: robocopy

There is this option in Robocopy:
/maxage:     Specifies the maximum file age (to exclude files older than N days or date).

In my case, i want to copy all data put into a new folder being created everyday by my colleagues.
The data usually contain files older than the date they are copied into.
In other words, can Robocopy copy all data by the date of containing folder?

Hope you can help me solve this problem. Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 0):

The below links are helpful and have the solution for your question

[Robocopy command to copy updated files and long path names](https://superuser.com/questions/1519537/robocopy-command-to-copy-updated-files-and-long-path-names)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064976/how-to-use-robocopy-to-copy-files-with-timestamp-in-command-line

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.