# Copy files except when destination modified in last x days

Tags: windows, powershell, robocopy, xcopy, copy

I think what I am trying to do is simple, but I can't get the `robocopy` settings right, as I am trying to copy files from `src` to `dest`, over-writing files in `dest` if they already exist, except if modified in the past 7 days.

- `/minage:7` seems to not copy files if they were modified on the `src` instead of what I want [`dest`], unless I am missing something.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried `/maxage:7`? _(Also, please add the command being used to the question inside a code box.)_

Answer (score 0):

I posted a solution for a thread similar to yours, and I hope this will help you

[Robocopy command to copy updated files and long path names](https://superuser.com/questions/1519537/robocopy-command-to-copy-updated-files-and-long-path-names/1522132#1522132)

and if you have any question, please don't hesitate to comment