# robocopy: copy only newer files whose older version are already in the destination folder (updating files, not folder)

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, robocopy

To update the files in the destination folder, I'd like to copy only the newer files whose older version are already in the destination folder.

I don't want to copy any files that are in the source folder but not in the destination folder.

This way, I'd not increase the number of files in the destination folder, only updating the existing files in the destination folder.

Example:

- Source directory:

  ```
  A.txt   2020-08-25  
  B.txt   2020-09-13  
  C.txt   2020-05-03
  ```
- Destination directory:

  ```
  B.txt   2020-08-09  
  C.txt   2020-05-03
  ```

In this case, only **`B.txt`** should be copied because:

**a)** `A.txt`   Doesn't exist in the destination folder, so, don't copy it,
**b)** `B.txt`   In the destination folder is older, so, copy it,
**c)** `C.txt`   In the destination isn't older, so don't copy it.

---

- Can **`RoboCopy`** do this, or I need a batch file?

Answer (score 1):

many ideas here in this link for the same issue if you need to copy only the new data to the destination folder
[Robocopy command to copy updated files and long path names](https://superuser.com/questions/1519537/robocopy-command-to-copy-updated-files-and-long-path-names/1522132#1522132)

Comment: Thanks but none of the suggested methods works for me (I didn't check the 3rd party software solutions.) I'm trying to update files, not the folder. All those files in the source folder that are not already in the destination folder should not be copied. I only want to copy the newer files which already exist in the destination folder. For example, if the source folder has two files, a.txt and b.txt and the destination folder has b.txt. I don't want a.txt copied and I want b.txt copied only if its version (date) in the source folder is newer.

Comment: XCOPY might do the job. Try XCOPY /? for help on all the options. I think XCOPY source destination /D /U would do what you're after.

Comment: @Steve Rindsberg Thanks. XCOPY /U /D /E worked the wonder.

Answer (score 0):

> Disclaimer: I was looking for exactly the same problem when I found
> this question. I'm somewhat surprised to find the answer only in a
> comment to a not-accepted answer, so I'm essentially just
> re-iterating what [Steve Rindsberg](https://superuser.com/users/166321/steve-rindsberg) commented above.

Using `XCOPY SrcFolder [DstFolder] /U /D [/E]` is doing exactly what was asked for, with:

- `SrcFolder` being the repository folder containing newer files
- `DstFolder` being were to copy to (and where to look up what to copy). This is optional if the command is run from within `DstFolder`
- `/U` Copies only files that already exist in destination.
- `/D` Copies files whose source time is newer than the destination time.
- `/E` Extend this like-for-like copy to sub-directories.

I also found it useful to just output what will be copied (without actually doing it), for which one can use

`XCOPY SrcFolder [DstFolder] /U /D [/E] /Y /F /L`

- `/L` Displays files that would be copied.
- `/Y` Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file.
- `/F` Displays full source and destination file names while copying.