# robocopy ignores modified files

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I'm cloning a directory with `robocopy`. My intention is cloning everything, purging extra files in the destination and also overwriting files that are the same according to size and timestamp (/IS option)

My command is
`& ROBOCOPY $SourcePath $DestinationPath /MIR /IS /R:2` (I'm using PowerShell)

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : 
   Source : C:\A
     Dest : C:\B

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /PURGE /MIR /IS /R:2 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :        22         0         0         0         0         0
   Files :       234       232         2         0         0         0
   Bytes :   80.82 m   76.88 m    3.93 m         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
   Ended :
```

**I don't understand why there are 2 skipped files** - also I'm unable to find mention of this issue on the internet.

I'm launching this command in a remote PowerShell session. I'm not sure if it's relevant but this seem to happen especially in the remote session.

- In the detailed output all but two files have status *Same* and no progress indicator.
- Two files have status *Older* and the copy progress indication 0%-100%. So it seems only these two have been copied.

This is apparently the opposite of ROBOCOPY report above so I'm a bit confused.

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Running with `/v` will give a verbose list that includes the two skipped files. If no reason is listed for the skip, try to copy them manually to see if any error arrives.

Comment: Thaks @harrymc. Running with /V shows two more files in the list with status modified that were not in previous list but no more info.

Comment: What happens when copying them manually?

Comment: If I log on the machine I can copy all the files manually without errors (of course I have to confirm overwriting). Robocopy also shows no error, retry or locked files at all. Just the list of files with the statuses and the puzzling (for me) final report

Comment: The remote session might lack some permissions?

Comment: I would exclude this - also no evidence of any permission error

Comment: I've tried deleting the copied files and launching the copy - now all listed files have copy progress indicator NOT only the non "same" files. I really seems like /IS is ignored. Also If I launch the copy (with a non empty target folder) with or without /IS the summary is the same.

Comment: @smv What's up, still having trouble with this, I have an idea that might help and I think it could be related to using the `/MIR` which; simply omit it. So I suggest you use a command something like this instead and then check your log file or output for that anomaly: `ROBOCOPY $SourcePath $DestinationPath "*.*" /S /E /PURGE /IS /ZB /R:2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to add `/it` option to include tweaked files.

Comment: Thanks, tweaked files were the issue but I was confused by robocopy report. For an explanation of how robocopy classifies files: https://superuser.com/questions/314503/what-does-robocopy-mean-by-tweaked-lonely-and-extra

Comment: @smv You are welcome. You can also upvote the answer if you like it.

Comment: @smv In [Microsoft Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) they are called modified files.